# AWS SDK for Ruby - Stub Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm having some trouble stubbing data with the AWS SDK for Ruby.

I'm making a call to admin_create_user and would like to sub the data on my tests.

If I just do something like:

```
Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new.stub_data(:admin_create_user)
```

It stubs the data, but the user has no attributes. I would like to have some specific attributes so I tried doing:

```
Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new.stub_data(:admin_create_user, user: { attributes: [{ name: 'sub', value: some_user_id }] })
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How do I correctly stub the data to put the information I want?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it results, if you want to stub_data on your rspec tests you need to do as follows:

```
Aws.config = {
  stub_responses: {
    admin_create_user: { user: { attributes: [{ name: 'sub', value: some_user_id }] } }
  }
}
```

Which will change AWS configuration **globally** so it will be changed for the following requests even if they are on different contexts.

Comment: I would recommend using Webmock https://github.com/bblimke/webmock, if you do you might want to set `WebMock.disable_net_connect!`